# Wave Optics: Geometrical path length vs Optical path length

Tags: optics, interference

I have  been solving a physics question requiring me to find the position of first maximum in case of the following situation. Given focal length as 20 cm of the lenses cut into half ans light of wavelength 476 nm.

[image]

I deduced that the light rays will not intersect each other but will have some gap.The book tells that S1 and S2 act as secondary sources. My doubt is

1. why would S1 and S2 be acting as secondary point source? How and why diffraction pattern will be formed?
2. Which path will be the optical path and geometrical path and why?

I am not able to procced solving the question without having the above concept cleared.
I have attached the solution given in the book below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. S1 and S2 are images of S from the lower and upper lenses, respectively.  As such, they act as point sources.  Note, the fact that each lens is a half of a lens, the resulting image won't be a strict point source.
2. An optical path is define as the index of refraction (n) multiplied by the length (L) the optical ray takes within that medium with that 'n'.  Then you add up all the contributions from start to the end point to compute the resulting total optical path. So, if the lenses are in free space, you'll have length of  ray S-C + n(of the lens)x(thickness of the lens) + C-S1 length.

Comment: I understood the first part. But in the second part the solution in the reference book has taken path difference a (AS2 + S2Y) - (AS1+S1X) . Can you confirm which one is correct?

Comment: Those are path differences, and they important to understand any diffraction pattern that you observe in the plane containing (O, X, Y).  So, I wouldn't call this optical path, I would call it the optical path difference.

Comment: optical path difference is difference in optical paths so why is your expression and the books different?

Comment: According to you optical path is S-C + n(of the lens)x(thickness of the lens) + C-S1 length but in the book it is AS2+S2Y?

Comment: Because I computed the total optical path for each segment, upper and lower.  To arrive at the expression in your comment you'll need to take the difference.  Note, the optical paths through the lenses are equal in both segments, so they subtract to zero.  Thus, the index of refraction becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the answer to your question: "why would S1 and S2 be acting as secondary point source? "

---

There are several essentially equivalent ways of defining geometrical optics, one way is Fermat's principle according to which between two fixed points light takes the shortest, or more precisely the 1st order *stationary* path, and this principle is also equivalent to Snell's law or refraction.

Another and completely equivalent way is to define special surfaces called *wavefronts*, note: we are still talking about geometrical optics, as ones whose gradients are the light rays themselves, that is the rays are orthogonal to these special surfaces, and instead of talking about trajectories, that is rays, along which light propagates we can talk about surfaces that are propagating.

From Fermat's theorem one can show that the optical path length along any rays between two such *wavefronts* is constant and is equal to the time of flight. Rays define wavefronts and wavefronts define rays*. When a wavefront surface degenerates into a single point we call it a focal point**, and consequently the time of flight along a ray connecting two focal points depends only on the two focal points and not on the ray.
Therefore, $S_1$ (or $S_2$) acts individually as secondary point source *coherent* with the one at $S$.

---

*This ray - wavefront *duality* is the geometrical optics version of Huygens principle.
**This is here they part paths, true wavefronts in EM can never degenerate to a single point, they minimum size is always on the order of a wavelength.